# How to get different JSON content in the same $http.get

Tags: angularjs, json, spring-mvc, dto

I'm using AngularJS to retrieve a list of objects from a Server. The server side is being made with Spring MVC.

So, I'd like to return a list of these objects as JSON format, but, I'd like to return an informative message object if the server coudn't retrieve the data for any reason.

Can I do it without encapsulating the List<> and the Message objects in a DTO (Data Transfer Object)?
How can I check on AngularJS the received JSON if it can be from 2 different types?

Here is a fragment of my controller class. It currently returns a list of the **MyType** I'd like to return. But the idea is to convert it to a generic type (Object, maybe?) and return from this request the list or the message, depending on the case.

```
@RequestMapping(value = RestPaths.LIST_MYTYPE_BY_OWNER, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<MyType> listByOwner(@RequestBody Owner o) {
    List<MyType> myType = myService.list(o);
    return myType;
}
```

This is the service that consults the controller. How could I treat the data, considering that the JSON could have different formats?

```
this.listMyType = function(ownerId){
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $http.get('/rest/my/list_by_owner',{})
    .then(function (response) {
        if (response.status == 200) {
            deferred.resolve(response.data);
        }
        else {
            deferred.reject('Error retrieving list of myType');
        }
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: conditional inside `then` function won't do anything since anything other than status 200 won't fire the first `then` function. It would fire the second argument function or `catch()`. Can send server side error messages with different status and use `then` rejection handler to manage response or send an `errors` property and check for that in the resolve handler

Comment: @charlietfl other than status 2xx would be more accurate.

Comment: @charlietfl, thanks for the tip, but it doens't regards the core of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use an exception for flow control. If both cases (list is empty or it is not) are valid, handle both of them in your handler method. Use [`ResponseEntity`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html) to encapsulate your response. Return a `String` message in one case (empty) and a `List<MyType>` in the other (not empty).

```
@RequestMapping(value = RestPaths.LIST_MYTYPE_BY_OWNER, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<?> listByOwner(@RequestBody Owner o) {
    List<MyType> myType = myService.list(o);
    if (myType.isEmpty()) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>("The message", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(myType, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

All handler method return values are handled by [`HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/support/HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler.html) objects. The corresponding one for `ResponseEntity` is [`HttpEntityMethodProcessor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/HttpEntityMethodProcessor.html). It handles the `ResponseEntity`'s [`body`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpEntity.html#getBody--) the same way [`@ReponseBody`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.html) would.

So a `String` would be written directly to the response as `text/plain` (or html) and the `List<MyType>` would be serialized to `application/json` by default (or whatever you have configured).

You can add response headers to the `ResponseEntity` which can also help determine how the content will be serialized (content-type, etc.).

Comment: http status codes in the 400s are non-successful requests, so using an exception to return the error code is not the same as using exceptions for flow control.

Comment: My interpretation of OP's question is that an _empty list_ is not an exceptional case (or failed case). I therefore wouldn't use an exception to handle it, regardless of the status code.

Comment: This is getting interesting. As I see, independently of the solution I use (as a thrown exception, or handling it on Controller method), the main idea is retrieve from server a HttpStatus, which will guide the angularJS service to the expected result. I didn't knew about ResponseEntity, and it gives more flexibility to HTTP responses.

Comment: I liked your solution, for it allows me to encapsulate a Message object (which I currently have one implemented) to my response, and giving the opportunity to retrieve more elaborated data on the body. The only question is: you both suggested HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND. Http code 204 seems to be more appropriate, although it doesn't expects some body content.

Comment: @marionmaiden You can use whatever status code is appropriate for your business logic. These are just examples.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to throw an exception, then add in a spring exception handler which sets the appropriate status code and message:

```
@RequestMapping(value = RestPaths.LIST_MYTYPE_BY_OWNER, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<MyType> listByOwner(@RequestBody Owner o) {
    List<MyType> myType = myService.list(o);
    if (myType.size() == 0) {
        throw new ResourceNotFoundException("List was empty");
    }
    return myType;
}
```

and

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ControllerExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(ResourceNotFoundException.class)
    public void handleException(Exception e, HttpServletReponse response) {
        response.setStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        response.getOutputStream().write(e.message);
    }
}
```

Here is a pretty good write up on spring mvc exception handling: https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc

Comment: Didn't know why someone downvoted your question. I thought it is an interesting option, for we can manage the response code status on client side. At home I'll try your solution!